# C# - How to implement multiple comparers for an IComparable<T> class?

Tags: c#, sorting, compare, icomparable

I have a class that implements IComparable.

```
public class MyClass : IComparable<MyClass>
{
    public int CompareTo(MyClass c)
    {
        return this.whatever.CompareTo(c.whatever);
    }

    etc..
}
```

I then can call the sort method of a generic list of my class

```
List<MyClass> c = new List<MyClass>();
//Add stuff, etc.

c.Sort();
```

and have the list sorted according to my comparer.

How do i specify further comparers to sort my collection different ways according to the other properties of MyClass in order to let users sort my collection in a number of different ways?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To setup the sort in your class:

```
public static Comparison<MyClass> OtherComparison = delegate(MyClass object1, MyClass object2)
{
    return object1.Whatever.CompareTo(object2.Whatever);
};
```

Then to sort using your new comparison:

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();
myClassList.Sort(MyClass.OtherComparison);
```

Except you clearly will not want to sort an empty list :)

Comment: +1 although you could write that more succinctly with a lambda expression :)

Comment: Kevin, I've struggled with this for 2 days now, and I can't understand what it is doing. Your way does work, but how would this static method be written without writing it as `delegate`?

Comment: @jp2code This answer actually got me thinking more deeply about comparisons. I asked a question about it, and I really like the accepted answer. See if that helps you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488298/advantages-disadvantages-of-different-implementations-for-comparing-objects-usin

Answer (score 9):

You can call Sort with a specific comparer as the argument. Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx)

Comment: I upvoted this answer as Kevin's because I think they are both good solutions.  I used this solution because I think it is simpler. itemDescription/ItemNumber:  I have provided an answer that demonstrates my implementation

Answer (score 3):

One step in that direction would be to use the Sort overload that let's you specify an `IComparer<T>` (not an `IComparable<T>`, though).

If you already have a lot of `IComparable<T>` implementations, it should be trivial to write a general-purpose implementation of `IComparer<T>` that compares two `IComparable<T>` instances. In fact, I'm a bit surprised such a class doesn't already exist in the BCL, but I haven't been able to find one.

`Comparer<T>.Default` comes close, but not quite.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple ways to sort a list of your objects, you obviously have to specify which option to choose. That's what the other overrides of Sort are good for. Have a look at IComparer and Comparison.