# Comparing for sorting in different ways

Tags: c#, sorting, compare, icomparable

I have a class that implements *IComparable*. It works but the comparison is static, i.e. it's always the same *ordering* it achieves. What would be a good method to introduce comparison by a parameter, i.e. if we have:

```
class Poo : IComparable { 
  public int A { ... };
  public int B { ... };
  ... 
}
IEnumerable<Foo> list = ...;
list = list.Sort(???);
```

I' d like to order the list with respect to *A* or *B* depending on the parameter passed to *Sort* at the question marks. What's the most efficient way to do that?

At the moment, the best method I've came up with is to declare a couple of methods that I pass to *Sort* as delegates.

```
private static int CompareWrtA(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) { ... }
private static int CompareWrtB(Foo foo1, Foo foo2) { ... }

if(withRespectToA)
  list = list.Sort(CompareWrtA);
else
  list = list.Sort(CompareWrtB);
```

But it doesn't feel really as the best way. Criticism is welcome.

Comment: so what do you want actually ? do you want to simplify this ? or do you want a solution to handle the situtation when you have more parameters and conditions for sorting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - How to implement multiple comparers for an IComparable<T> class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480111/c-sharp-how-to-implement-multiple-comparers-for-an-icomparablet-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simplify that statement you can write it like this:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => withRespectToA ? CompareWrtA(x,y) : CompareWrtB(x,y));
```

BTW, `Sort` method is modifying your list, it doesn't return anything.So you don't need to assign it back to your list.

Comment: I just want to know if the approach I took is the optimal one. From your reply I take it is. Thanks for the mutability remark.   :)