# Set rank based on Value in List

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting

I am trying to find better way to solve my problem.
I have a list with properties. Some properties should be "ranked" (who is better).

Here are data structures:

```
public class MovieRankData
{
    public Guid MovieId { get; set; }
    public RankData TotalViews { get; set; }
    public RankData TotalMoney { get; set; }
}

public class RankData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double? Value { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

And very simple code (please see comments):

```
var movieRankData = new List<MovieRankData>
{
    new MovieRankData
    {
        MovieId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        TotalViews = new RankData {Name = "Total Movie View", Value = 985 },    // Rank should be 2 (of 3)
        TotalMoney = new RankData {Name = "Total Movie Money", Value = 525.12}, // Rank should be 1 (of 3)
    },

    new MovieRankData
    {
        MovieId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        TotalViews = new RankData {Name = "Total Movie View", Value = 812},  // Rank should be 3 (of 3)
        TotalMoney = new RankData {Name = "Total Movie Money", Value = 100}, // Rank should be 3 (of 3)
    },

    new MovieRankData
    {
        MovieId = Guid.Empty,
        TotalViews = new RankData {Name = "Total Movie View", Value = 1000}, // Rank should be 1 (of 3)
        TotalMoney = new RankData {Name = "Total Movie Money", Value = 321}, // Rank should be 2 (of 3)
    }
};
```

I came up with ugly foreach, many temporary variables to compare and set Rank property.

What is the better way to go through each element, compare it to others and to rate it?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: It looks like "Rank" is just a simplification of "Value".  I'm not sure what Rank's purpose is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
var byTotalViews = movieRankData.OrderByDescending(m => m.TotalViews.Value).ToList();
var byTotalMoney = movieRankData.OrderByDescending(m => m.TotalMoney.Value).ToList();

foreach (var movie in movieRankData)
{
    movie.TotalViews.Rank = byTotalViews.IndexOf(movie) + 1;
    movie.TotalMoney.Rank = byTotalMoney.IndexOf(movie) + 1;
}
```

Though this does not handle `null` values for `TotalViews` and `TotalMoney`. If you tell me what to do in that case, I'll modify my answer. My current solution assigns the highest ranks to `null`s because of the way nullable comparison works.

A reasonable solution would be to make `Rank` nullable too and set it to `null` if `Value` is `null`.

**EDIT:** please also read @GiladGreen's suggestion in the comments for a performance improvement.

**EDIT 2:** here is the Dictionary-based version that will perform well on large collections. First we define a function to calculate the ranks and store them in a dictionary:

```
private static Dictionary<MovieRankData, int> CalculateRanks(
    List<MovieRankData> movieRankData, 
    Func<MovieRankData, double?> orderKeySelector)
{
    return movieRankData
        .OrderByDescending(orderKeySelector)
        .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
        .ToDictionary(e => e.item, e => e.index + 1);
}
```

Then we use the function to generate the `byTotalViews` and `byTotalMoney` dictionaries:

```
var byTotalViews = CalculateRanks(movieRankData, m => m.TotalViews.Value);
var byTotalMoney = CalculateRanks(movieRankData, m => m.TotalMoney.Value);

foreach (var movie in movieRankData)
{
    movie.TotalViews.Rank = byTotalViews[movie];
    movie.TotalMoney.Rank = byTotalMoney[movie];
}
```

Comment: For big `moveRankData` collections better store the results of the sorting as a `HashSet` rather a list so locating it in the `foreach` would be o(n) instead of o(n^2)

Comment: @GiladGreen as far as I know, HashSet does not preserve order.

Comment: Though converting the lists to a `Dictionary<MovieRankData, int>` where the values are the indices of the list would indeed be much more efficient.

Comment: True. Slipped my mind :) One can add this: `.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })`  after the ordering or just `ToDictionary`

Comment: @Gilad Green, sorry for being stupid, but how it will improve performance?

Comment: @J.DoeJr. - Not being stupid at all. Locating an object in a list is of o(n) while in a HashSet it is o(1). meaning that because it is in the look it will be in a total complexity of o(n) instead of o(n^2). Imagine your collections has 10^4 items -> its the difference between 10^4 operations to 10^8 operations..

Comment: In my original solution, the `IndexOf` calls iterate over the lists (`byTotalViews` and `byTotalMoney`) to find the right `MovieRankData` instance *for each movie*. If you have *n* movies, the time it takes for the `foreach` loop to complete will be proportional to *n^2*. A hash set or a dictionary is optimized for this exact case - lookup always takes a constant amount of time, independent of the number of items.

Comment: Thank you guys for your explanations!

Comment: @J.DoeJr. if you have found the answers to your questions helpful, don't forget to upvote them! If you think one of them has solved your problem, mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: Well, I like your and @Me.Name answers, I am thinking on merging them. It is very sad that I can choose only 1 answer.

Answer (score 0):

*See Botond Balázs's answer for the simpler solution*

Inherit the IComparable Interface and implement the CompareTo Method as you wish.
Example:

```
class MovierankData:IComparable
{
    public int CompareTo(MovierankData obj)
    {
        if(this.Value > obj.Value)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(this.Value < obj.Value)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.Name.CompareTo(obj.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

You can now call yourlist.Sort() and it will get sorted by Value and if Values are the same they will be ordered by their name.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about implementing IComparable, but didn't find a way to set rank for every element.

Comment: @J.DoeJr. and @LukasPöhn it is RankData that should implement `IComparable`

Comment: @Botond Balázs , Am I right, that if I will apply IComparrable to RankData, then I could do inplace Sort() in foreach loop from your soultion?

Comment: Do you mean sorting inside the `foreach` loop? I wouldn't recommend that because it is very inefficient.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. You would need 2 comparers in the MovierankData Class [HowTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480111/c-sharp-how-to-implement-multiple-comparers-for-an-icomparablet-class) and with those call the standard '[int].Compare()'.

Comment: Please also note that `double?` already implements `IComparable` so you don't need to - I've just realized this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom IComparer that compares between the MovieRankData elements and use the Lists Sort method.

See an example here (take a look at the second answer too):
[LINQ Custom Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841170/linq-custom-sort)

Answer (score 0):

In the following, your `index` + 1 is the value of your `rank`, if `rank` 1 is lowest.

```
movieRankData.OrderBy(t => t.TotalViews.Value);
movieRankData.OrderBy(t => t.TotalMoney.Value);
```

Or this for `rank` 1 being the highest:

```
movieRankData.OrderByDesc(t => t.TotalViews.Value);
movieRankData.OrderByDesc(t => t.TotalMoney.Value);
```

In either case, you can use a `for loop` to set the `rank` equal to the `index` of the `object` in the `collection` + 1

```
for(int i = 0; i < movieRankData.Count(); i++)
{
        movieRankData[i].TotalViews.Rank = 
        movieRankData.OrderByDesc(t => t.TotalViews.Value).IndexOf(movieRankData[i]) + 1;

  }
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, and even if it did, it would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: That's what happens when I misclick and post before I'm done typing....Should be fine now.  But yes, ideally you'd want to only execute the Linq once, outside of the loop.

Comment: Except that is still isn't fine... have you actually tried to run it?

Answer (score 0):

Using a select overload with the index on orderby results, you only have to loop each collection once. For maintainability a helper function could be used to set the rank of a specific property. This would have the added benefit that if an extra ranking is added, the function call can be added for that ranking:

```
void SetRank(IEnumerable<MovieRankData> list, Func<MovieRankData,RankData> prop)
{
    foreach(var ri in list.Select(prop).OrderByDescending(r=>r.Value).Select((r,i)=> new{r,i}))
            ri.r.Rank = ri.i + 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
SetRank(movieRankData, m => m.TotalViews);
SetRank(movieRankData, m => m.TotalMoney);
```

(Or keep the properties to be called in a lambda array and call the function  for each)